# Где тут сказуемое?

Tags: синтаксис

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где сказуемое в предложении "Иду курю"?

Comment: Надо просто бросить курить - тогда и вопроса не будет! ;-)))

Comment: Или хотя бы не курить стоя.

Comment: Еще хуже - на ходу и кого-то обгоняя )).

Comment: Сказуемое 'иду курю'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это предложение разговорное, разговорный язык не всегда следует строгим литературным нормам, поэтому синтаксический разбор бывает затруднителен.

Скорее всего в данном варианте "иду" приобретает модальное значение, которого оно не имеет в литературном языке, либо значение обстоятельства цели (ср.: "сижу пишу" - сижу с целью писать). В этом случае "иду курю" - главный член предложения. Но повторяю, это не более чем грамматические окказионализмы разговорного языка.

Нормативным вариантом было бы писать через запятую: "иду, курю" и рассматривать "иду" и "курю" как однородные главные члены (сказуемые) односоставного предложения.

Answer (score 2):

Несмотря на то что это предложение носит разговорный характер, в учебниках для вузов и в школьных учебниках такие примеры есть как примеры простого глагольного сказуемого. Некоторые, например Валгина,  называют его простым осложненным глагольным сказуемым. Если бы второй глагол был в форме инфинитива - иду курить - тогда сказуемое "иду", обстоятельство цели "курить".

И в качестве пояснения для  cat - если Вы учитесь в школе, то допустимо, говоря про  односоставное предложение, употреблять термин "сказуемое". А вообще -то в односоставном предложении есть просто "главный член". Сказуемое есть там, где есть подлежащее, т.е. в двусоставном предложении.

Comment: Лариса, а разве об односоставном предложении не говорят, что в нем не сказуемое, грамматическая основа предложения?

Comment: Не поняла вопроса, вроде бы я понятно написала. Или Вы про школу?  В школе традиционно сохраняется для односоставного терминология двусоставного: подлежащее, сказуемое. Хотя в гуманитарных классах (или просто сильным учащимся) мы об этом говорим.

Comment: Спасибо за оперативность, но я спрашивал, действительно ли в односоставном предложении употребляется термин "главный член предложения"? Я привык к выражению "грамматическая основа предложения представлена сказуемым (или подлежащим)". Разве так сейчас не говорят?

Comment: Снова не уточнили - где? Да и как я за всех отвечу?. Я знаю, что в односоставном нет ни подлежащего, ни сказуемого. То, что есть,- этот грамматическая основа, главный член предложения.  И так. и так верно. Именно  такими словами, как Вы привели, я не говорю. С университетских времен помню выражение: главный член предложения, по форме похожий на сказуемое (подлежащее). Для краткости и ясности (подчеркиваем -то все равно, как сказуемое или подлежащее)в школе сохраняется терминология двусоставного предложения.

Comment: >Я знаю, что в односоставном нет ни подлежащего, ни сказуемого
  
Ларf, это не так. От того, что сказуемое обозвали (относительно, кстати, недавно - лет пятьдесят тому назад) "главным членом", оно сказуемым быть не перестало. Это не вопрос школьной краткости и ясности, это вопрос терминологии, так что заостряться не нужно. С остальным - согласен: по нынешней терминологии "главный член предложения" - наиболее используемая форма при описании односоставных предложений.

Comment: Не соглашусь с Вами. Подлежащее - предмет речи, сказуемое - то, что говорится о предмете речи. Нет подлежащего. нет и сказуемого. (Очень логично, на мой взгляд. Я это помню очень хорошо. Проходила специализацию на кафедре языка, и у нас курс такой был - точно название курса не припомню, но суть в сравнении школьной и научной грамматики. Да посмотрите хоть учебник Валгиной. Там, где она говорит об односоставных предложениях, термина подлежащее-сказуемое  нет!

Comment: То, что Валгина не говорит, ничего не доказывает. Она просто уходит от терминологической путаницы. Просто в двусоставных предложениях представлены **два главаных члена**:  подлежащее и сказуемое, в односоставном естественно - один. Но какой? 
Требование "без подлежащего нет сказуемого", естественно, ни в какой ьграмматике не может быть определяющим, поскольку в основу кладутся определения и того и другого.

А чем ещё можно аргументировать? Кроме Вашей уверенности? 

Вообще терминология на мой вкус удачнее всего изложена http://www.gramma.ru/RUS/?id=5.18

Comment: Чисто теоретически могу представить 3 ситуации: 1. Односоставное предложение с подлежащим. 2. Односоставное предложение со сказуемым. 3. Односоставное предложение с членом, точную принадлежность которого определить трудно.  

Думаю, третий класс имеет право на существование. Иначе не было бы столько вопросов - сказуемое или подлежащее?

Answer (score 1):

Насколько мне помнится, это пелось группою "Ноль", сочинитель Федя Чистяков. Вот:

http://www.moskva.fm/artist/%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C/song_699887

Текст нотируют по-разному, но на слух это всё-таки, на мой взгляд, два определённо-личных предложения:

> Иду. Курю.

Тогда вопрос, где сказуемое, не возникает.)))